# In LaTeX3, how do I peek ahead for an active character?

Tags: expl3, active-characters

LaTeX3 defines the `\peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NTF` which allows me to look ahead at the next token in the stream (ignoring spaces) and test its catcode against those of a slew of standard tokens.  So I can do:

```
\peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NTF \c_math_toggle_token
{
Uh-oh,~ upcoming~ math!
}
{
Phew!~ Just~ text.
}
```

to see if what's next is a math shift.

How do I do the same but for an active character?  There's no `\c_active_token` that I can test against.  I've tried making one by emulating the code that makes the other tokens, but my attempts have failed dismally.  There's a `\c_catcode_active_tl` that *contains* an active token, but it contains it with an `\exp_not:N` so even doing

```
\exp_last_unbraced:NV \peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NTF \c_catcode_token_tl
```

doesn't work.

Yet there is a `\token_if_active:NTF` so I presume I could cobble together some variant of the peek code that tested for an active character by effectively copying the code that defines `\peek_catcode_stuff` and swapping the tests.  But before I attempt that, I thought I'd ask if there's something I'm missing.

So, is there a straightforward way to see if the next character is active?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're almost there.  `\exp_last_unbraced:NV` expands `\c_catcode_active_tl` only once, then

```latex
\exp_last_unbraced:NV \peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NTF \c_catcode_active_tl
  { true } { false }
```

becomes

```latex
\peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NTF \exp_not:N % <- test token
  * % <- true branch
  { true } % <- false branch
  { false } % <- leftover
```

then things go horribly wrong :)

Since the active token in `\c_catcode_active_tl` is preceded by `\exp_not:N`, you can safely `x`-expand it to expose the actual token:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npx \test
  {
    \peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NTF \c_catcode_active_tl
      { \exp_not:N \__test_aux:Nn \c_true_bool }
      { \exp_not:N \__test_aux:Nn \c_false_bool }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__test_aux:Nn #1 #2
  { \iow_term:x { \bool_if:NF #1 { NOT~an~ } active~token:~\tl_to_str:n {#2} } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\test ~
\test a
\test \stop
\test \relax
\test {ab}

\stop
```

The test above prints:

```
active token: ~
non-active token: a
non-active token: \stop
non-active token: \relax
non-active token: ab
```

P.S.:  There is no `\c_catcode_active_token` because doing `\let \c_catcode_active_token <actual active token>` would make `\c_catcode_active_token` a regular macro with the same definition as the `<actual active token>`, which would be of no use in this case.

Comment: you beat me to it, but I was going to suggest e not x :-) `\exp_args:Ne\peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NTF \c_catcode_active_tl `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Since there isn't a `\cs_...:Npe` then one difference between Phelype's solution and yours is that Phelype's does the expansion once at definition time whereas yours does it every time at invocation.  Also, Phelype's expands the whole definition whereas yours only expands the `\c_catcode_active_tl`. Are there other significant differences?

Comment: Phelype, this is fantastic.  It's working perfectly in my code.

Comment: @AndrewStacey no real differences other than that  (which is why I didn't post my full  example) but I could do if you think it's useful to compare

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think it's always useful to have alternatives (and one of the things I value having on this site). It could be edited in to this answer as a variation (if Phelype's happy with that), but I don't see any problem with having it as a separate answer either.

Comment: @AndrewStacey What David said: The only practical difference is that using `\exp_args:N(e|x)` here will be a tiny bit slower (expanding once vs. expanding on every usage).  Other than that, either version and either `x` or `e` have the same effect.  Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative way to extract the active character token from `\c_catcode_active_tl` is to use `\exp_args:Ne`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\zzMath{}{
\peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NTF \c_math_toggle_token
{
Uh-oh,~ upcoming~ math!
}
{
Phew!~ Just~ text.
}
}

\NewDocumentCommand\zzActive{}{
\exp_args:Ne\peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NTF \c_catcode_active_tl 
{
Uh-oh,~ upcoming~ active!
}
{
Phew!~ Just~ text.
}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

[\zzMath abc] [\zzMath $x=2$] [\zzMath ~zz]


[\zzActive abc] [\zzActive $x=2$] [\zzActive ~zz]

\end{document}
```